# why does - result-document method="text" - export an xml declaration?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

Sadly this question is wrong - i can't seem to replicate the behaviour, thanks to Martin Honnen below for forcing me to revisit my assumptions - I can't delete it.

Saxon 11.4

if I run this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document method="text" encoding="utf-8">
            <xsl:text>foo</xsl:text>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i would expect a text document

```
foo
```

but i get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>foo
```

I was trying to dynamically trying to select and output format based on a passed parameter, but obviously if i want a text output I don't want an xml declation in it.

P.S.

the input document can be any valid xml (unless I'm missing something)
so

```
<foo/>
```

Comment: What is the input? Is the shown result the primary or the secondary result document?

Comment: it doesnt matter what the input is does it?...it just matchs the root document node

Comment: Perhaps not but you haven't given enough detail for us or at least me to reproduce the result.

Comment: primary or secondary result?...hmmm...its just the output from the java saxon call, maybe this is the piece i dont understand, I'm just expecint the output to be in the specified "-o" file (which it is) and i expect it to be a text file, not text embedded in an xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us what the input is nor explained how exactly you run the transformation and look at the result but for me the (currently using SaxonJ HE 11.5) [XML workbench, with no input](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22xs%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20method%3D%22text%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atext%3Efoo%3C%2Fxsl%3Atext%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None), and the code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:result-document method="text" encoding="utf-8">
            <xsl:text>foo</xsl:text>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives just

```
foo
```

as the sole and principal result.

The [same result if I use some input](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22xs%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20method%3D%22text%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atext%3Efoo%3C%2Fxsl%3Atext%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Cfoo%2F%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

I have also run SaxonJ 11 from the command line (using the current/latest 11.6) and it doesn't show any XML declaration, neither when directly writing to the console nor when outputting to a file:

```
java -jar 'C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE11-6J\saxon-he-11.6.jar' -s:.\sample1.xml -xsl:.\sheet1.xsl
foo
PS C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Documents\xslt\blog-xslt-3-by-example\sole-xsl-result-doc-test> java -jar 'C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE11-6J\saxon-he-11.6.jar' -s:.\sample1.xml -xsl:.\sheet1.xsl -o:result1.txt
PS C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Documents\xslt\blog-xslt-3-by-example\sole-xsl-result-doc-test> type .\result1.txt
foo
```

So it is not quite clear what you are doing or in what way (command line, some API, some editor) your are using Saxon and get the result you show in your question.

Comment: let me add the command line...its just burried in some code

Comment: actually lets keep this simple.
if I use oxygen and give it the example input I have on the question it gives me the output i describe

Comment: actually - NO I DONT!...hmm

Comment: hmmmm...its not happening any more....ignore me...

Comment: I coudl do with giving you credit but deleting the question...its wrong.